# Function in makefile

Tags: makefile, alias

I have a function in my `.profile` which I need in a makefile (one of the first ones I ever made). As far as I can tell make doesn't allow for interactively defined functions or aliases

How can I still make use of the function? This is defined in my `.profile`:

```
matlabs(){
    /Applications/Matlab.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm -r "disp('MATLAB:');${1}; quit();" | tail -n +11
}
```

And I would like to do this in the makefile:

```
num.txt : finance.m
    matlabs finance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makefiles aren't shell scripts. What you can do is make a shell script out of your `matlabs` function; put the following in an executable file `matlabs` somewhere in your `PATH`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Matlab.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm \
   -r "disp('MATLAB:');${1}; quit();" \
  | tail -n +11
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the Makefile to depend on an external script and you need to do this transformation often, you can define an implicit Makefile rule for it:

```
%.txt : %.m
        @/Applications/Matlab.app/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nojvm \
            -r "disp('MATLAB:'); $<; quit();" \
            | tail -n +11 > "$@"
```